# Continuity of a function at x = 4

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

**Question**:

Let $f(x) =\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} (x^2 - 16) /(x-4) ,& {\rm if}~ x < 4, \\ cx^2 +8,& {\rm if}~ x \geq4. \end{array} \right. $

Discuss whether there is any value(s) of c such that $f(x)$ is contentious at $x = 4$.

**Attempt**:

To check the continuity of $f(x)$ at $x = 4$, we need to check if the left limit and right limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $4$ are equal, and if they are equal to $f(4)$.

We have,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to4^-} f(x) &= \lim_{x\to4^-} \frac{x^2 - 16}{x - 4} = 8.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to4^+} f(x) &= \lim_{x\to4^+} cx^2 + 8 = 16c + 8.
\end{align*}

Therefore, in order for $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x=4$, we need to have $8 = 16c+8$, which implies $c=0$. Thus, $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=4$ if and only if $c=0$.

Comment: If I’m being nitpicky you showed that $c = 0$ makes the limit exist but didn’t also confirm that it agrees with the function value: obviously it does in our case, so your answer isn’t wrong, but that would be my one problem with the way it’s written. Otherwise, looks completely perfect, good job.

Comment: Looks good.  If this is for homework, or something like that, you might want to elaborate on how the first limit is calculated.  You don't need to say much...just pointing out that $x^2-16=(x-4)(x+4)$ is enough.

Comment: (In the same vein as Stephen's comment) it would be (imo) smarter to notice first that whatever $c$'s value, $f$ will always be continuous on the right at $4$ (since it is polynomial on $[4,+\infty)$). So you just need to determine for which $c$'s the left limit is equal to $f(4).$